# A ball of ice melts so that its radius decreases from $5 cm$ to $4.92 cm$. By approximately how much does the volume of the ball decrease?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

The following exercise is presented in my book as an example of linear approximation and calculating the rate of change using derivatives. The rate of change for the volume gives $ \approx-25.13 cm^3 $

Taking aside the purpose of the example, I'm wondering if there's any practical reason to use calculus instead of taking the volume of the ball when it has $ 5cm $, the volume when it has $ 4.92cm $ and then calculating the difference of those two values. With this approach, the solution is $ \approx-24.73 cm^3 $

Is this approach also correct?

Comment: The point of the exercise is, I assume, to practice using the derivative for linear approximations.  Yes, in this case it's easy to compute the exact figure, but in many cases you will not be able to compute $F(x_0+\delta)$ exactly.  Here, you can compare the exact result to the one you get via linear approximation.

Comment: Yes, both approaches are basically correct. The point of the exercise is that the change in volume of a sphere is -in linear approximation- equal to the surface area of the sphere times the change in radius.